# jQuery animate 'right' position issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have a menu that slides through several sections of my Website, right and left.

Originally I had a function 'goto()', which was triggered 'onClick', and the animation worked exactly as expected.

I wanted to clean up the HTML, so I added a bind handler to a click event in a JS file.

```
var navanchors = $('#navMain a');
var slider = $('#slider');

init = function() {

navanchors.bind('click', function() {

    var t = $(this);
    var id = t.attr('href');
    var dist = $(id).position().left;

    //animate to the div id.
    slider.animate({
        "right": (dist)
    }, 600);

});
};

init();​
```

The left animation seems to work as expected, but the right animation is off. On the first click the animation seems to move twice the expected distance. On a second click it resets without animation.

Please have a look at the issue here: http://jsfiddle.net/Kj4bU/1

I have searched and experimented but am at a loss. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: FYI, I debugged using Firebug and the 'dist' value is correct each time. It just slides further for some reason when going right.

Comment: Here is an example with the console, displaying the div 'id' and the 'dist' value: http://jsbin.com/uxonas/2/edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not preventing the default behavior of the `click` events you handle from occurring. Since the clicks occur on anchor elements, the browser will try to scroll to the clicked anchor's position during your animation, resulting in the issue you're experiencing.

You can use [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault) to inhibit this behavior:

```
navanchors.on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var t = $(this);
    var id = t.attr("href");
    var dist = $(id).position().left;

    //animate to the div id.
    slider.animate({
        "right": dist
    }, 600);
});
```

You will find an updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Kj4bU/4/).

(Note the code above uses [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of [bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/), the former being preferred to the latter since jQuery 1.7).

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for the detailed explanation, and even going as far as updating a working version of the code.